# Tensor products of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Consider the class of complex algebras where the tensor products are over complex numbers.

> Given a complex algebra $A$ and a left ideal $L$ of $A$ generated by $n$ elements. Is $L^{\otimes n}$ principal in $A^{\otimes n}$?

Comment: Why do you think that this could be true? What should be the generator of $L^{\otimes n}$?

Comment: $a_1\otimes 1 \otimes 1 \ldots + 1 \otimes a_2 \otimes 1 \ldots + \ldots$ ?

Comment: How should that element generate $a_1\otimes1\otimes\ldots?$